# vb.NET set property of list member object

Tags: vb.net, list, properties, reference

I have a `List(Of Vector)` and want to set a property, eg. the Vector's `Y`, of one member of the list in a loop.
Why does this line not work?

```
vertices(i).Y = vertices(i).Y + vertices(i - 1).Y
```

but when I assign the property to a vector normally (vector isn't in a list) like this it works:

```
Dim testVertex As Vector = New Vector(0, 0)
testVertex.Y = vertices(i).Y + vertices(i - 1).Y
```

Using `vertices.Item(i).Y` doesn't work either.

Code I use is something like this:

```
Dim vertices As List(Of Vector) = New List(Of Vector)

' here we take absolute values in x-direction and
' relative values in y-direction which will be added up below

vertices.Add(New Vector(some_value, some_other_value))
' several more of the same line with other values

For i As Integer = 1 To vertices.Count - 1
    vertices(i).Y = vertices(i).Y + vertices(i - 1).Y
Next
```

This is especially confusing as I'm used to C style programming and this looks like something that could be easily solved using pointers. I'm not 100% sure what this code does in terms of references.

I think I could set the property using reflection, but I guess there is also a better way to do this. Another way to achieve what I want would be to create a temporary variable to store a copy of the vector, operate on it and then replace the list element with the copy.

Is there a way to do this more elegant? Something like `(getReference(vertices,i)).Y = ...`?

Error is [Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76435b93.aspx). Vector is [System.Windows.Vector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.aspx)

Comment: how does the first one "not work"?  what does that mean?

Comment: gets underlined red in visual studio, so cannot be built.

Comment: ...and if you hold the mouse over it what is the compiler error?

Comment: ah, error is "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment". MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76435b93.aspx but on MSDN the only help is you could use a temporary variable.

Comment: Sounds like X and Y are not properties/public fields.  Show the relevant parts of `Vector` using simple props it will work fine

Comment: but they are, as i described in the question this works: `testVertex.Y = vertices(i).Y + vertices(i - 1).Y`

Comment: ah, it's the vector from WindowsBase, `Import System.Windows`, in the definition `System.Windows.Vector` has `Public Property Y As Double`, comment says `Gets or sets the System.Windows.Vector.Y component of this vector.`

Comment: That is for WPF, is this winforms?

Comment: Try using the item property in the list: `vertices.Item(i).Y = ...`

Comment: it's a Windows Forms Application, but i don't think this is relevant to the problem; i've used Vectors before in the application without problems, just this assignment to a list's member's property fails.

Comment: same problem with `vertices.Item(i).Y`, i've tried this before, should have put this in the question, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that System.Windows.Vector is a value type (Structure).  When you access the instance in the List, you only get a copy of the data and the compiler recognizes that you are attempting to modify the copy.

You will have to create a temporary variable to hold the Vector instance and then set the properties and then reinsert it back into the list.  Something like this:

```
Dim vertices As List(Of Vector) = New List(Of Vector)

' here we take absolute values in x-direction and
' relative values in y-direction which will be added up below

vertices.Add(New Vector(some_value, some_other_value))
' several more of the same line with other values

For i As Integer = 1 To vertices.Count - 1
    'get a copy of the Vectors
    Dim vTmp1 As Vector = vertices(i)
    Dim vTmp2 As Vector = vertices(i - 1)

    'Set the values
    vTmp1.Y = vTmp1.Y + vTmp2.Y

    'Put it back into the list, overwriting the value that is already there
    vertices(i) = vTmp1
Next
```